# Move elements to top in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an object like this:

```
var obj = [
    { name: "name1", type: 4 },
    { name: "name6", type: 2 },
    { name: "name2", type: 5 }, 
    { name: "name3", type: 1 }, 
    { name: "name5", type: 2 }, 
    { name: "name4", type: 3 }
]
```

I want to return a sorted array, so that at the top of the array there are objects with type 2 or 3, sorted further by the name field:

```
var obj = [
    { name: "name4", type: 3 }
    { name: "name5", type: 2 },
    { name: "name6", type: 2 },
    { name: "name1", type: 4 },
    { name: "name2", type: 5 }, 
    { name: "name3", type: 1 } 
]
```

How can I implement this?

p.s.  I would also like to see a variant if type is enum (e.g.,

```
export enum Types {
Type0 = 0, 
Type1 = 1, 
.....}
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort first on whether the type is one of `2` or `3` (you can do this by checking whether the `type` value exists in an array `[2, 3]`; we sort that as a descending sort since we want `true` results first), and then on the name:

```js
var obj = [
    { name: "name1", type: 4 },
    { name: "name6", type: 2 },
    { name: "name2", type: 5 }, 
    { name: "name3", type: 1 }, 
    { name: "name5", type: 2 }, 
    { name: "name4", type: 3 }
]

const firstTypes = [2, 3]

obj.sort((a, b) =>
  firstTypes.includes(b.type) - firstTypes.includes(a.type) ||
  a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
)

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: ty! small question. If type is an enum (export enum Types {Type0 = 0, Type 1 = 1, .....}). Do I have to use Object.values somehow when sorting?

Comment: @Stranger it should just work as is: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2AZygb3kgDFAvFLAGlkWAEY8ozjNgAmSum0gZjxeaQBZKvPgArJSEBfAFBiAbgEMATlAD2AIwBWlANpio29FBDSIwAFxQARPsNlTxAC6kTtZADpaPEYS060eg8bMXgADZrKDskB1JnWgZ3T21vAJNzXzoQsL9HF1JRYjjdRP9fFjT7EiQo0gp3KDyE3ySAgRLwspQspBjcnXz6wsMuZozI9uA2cQBdCQBjBRBkGygAMwBLWXnHDUzo-gqkFkmxZRUnZAVZGwAKC+liJQBKPAA+TwA5SCVgWQuVtZtM5ZAUwANmAACYoC5KJzpO4PAC0UDeEA+Xx+62GAOBYIh0mhpFhUAAPoTPLiAk4gQoptIgcAAMIKCAIOTASFOAJ3MScsQzOYKWkUhQAcwuRzuQA